# Postgresql Insertion rule/trigger

Tags: postgresql

I have a problem on creating insertion rule or trigger for a table[t_1] in postgresql

The table has four columns: c1, c2, c3, c4, id(unique)
When a new record try to insert into table there are following rules:

1. If id is not duplicated, then do normal insertion with NEW record
2. If id is exists: then check c1,c2,c3 and NEW.c1, NEW.c2, NEW.c3; if c1 or c2 or c3 is not null then do update record and do not overwrite old record with new record.

For example

c1(not null),c2(null),c3(not null),c4(null)

+

nC1(not null),nC2(not null),nC3(null),nC4(null)

Result

c1, nC2, c3, c4

3. If id is exists: if new c4 is not null, then check old c1,c2,c3, if any of old c1,c2,c3 is not null then DO NOTHING(do not insert or update)

Here is my code currently:(still don't have solution for the 3rd condition)

```
  CREATE RULE "t_1_on_duplicate_ignore" AS ON INSERT TO "t_1"
  WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t_1
    WHERE (id)=(NEW.id)
DO INSTEAD
(
  UPDATE t_1 SET
    c1 = CASE 
    WHEN c1 IS NOT NULL
    THEN c1
    ELSE NEW.c1  
    END,
    c2 = CASE 
    WHEN c2 IS NOT NULL
    THEN c2
    ELSE NEW.c2
    END,
    c3 = CASE 
    WHEN c3 IS NOT NULL
    THEN c3
    ELSE NEW.c3
    END
  WHERE id = NEW.id;
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello guys I think I solved this problem(at least its works for me) with following commands:

```
      CREATE RULE "t_1_on_duplicate_ignore" AS ON INSERT TO "t_1"
      WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM t_1
        WHERE (id)=(NEW.id))
    DO INSTEAD
    (
        UPDATE t_1 SET
            c1 = CASE
            WHEN (c1 IS NOT NULL AND c4 IS NOT NULL) OR (c4 IS NULL AND c1 IS NOT NULL) OR (c4 IS NULL AND NEW.c4 IS NOT NULL)
            THEN c1
            ELSE NEW.c1
            END,
            c2 = CASE
            WHEN (c2 IS NOT NULL AND c4 IS NOT NULL) OR (c4 IS NULL AND c2 IS NOT NULL) OR (c4 IS NULL AND NEW.c4 IS NOT NULL)
            THEN c2
            ELSE NEW.c2
            END,
            c3 = CASE
            WHEN (c3 IS NOT NULL AND c4 IS NOT NULL) OR (c4 IS NULL AND c3 IS NOT NULL) OR (c4 IS NULL AND NEW.c4 IS NOT NULL)
            THEN c3
            ELSE NEW.c3
            END,
            c4 = c4
        WHERE id = NEW.id;
    )
```

Any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for MERGE/UPSERT?

http://michael.otacoo.com/postgresql-2/postgres-9-5-feature-highlight-upsert/
http://pgeoghegan.blogspot.com/2015/10/avoid-naming-constraint-directly-when.html
https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SQL_MERGE

Comment: I think its merge. is that new feature after 9.x?